# Spring Boot 2.1 : Exception thrown in WebMvcConfigurer#addFormatters(...) not catched in @RestControllerAdvice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

After updating from Spring Boot 2.0 to 2.1, all exceptions thrown in `WebMvcConfigurer#addFormatters( FormatterRegistry registry )` are no longer catched in the `@RestControllerAdvice`. I use this method for additionnal converters.

Eg.:

```
public class ConvertersContainer {

    public static class StringToStatusConverter implements Converter<String, Status> {

       @Override
       public Status convert( String source ) {
           return Status.findStatus( source );
       }
    }
}
```

And `Status` is an enum.

```
public enum Status {

   HAPPY("happy"), ANGRY("angry");

   private String title;

   public static Status findStatus( final String title) {
    return stream( values() )
            .filter( status-> status.getTitle().equals( title) )
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow( () -> new StatusNotFoundException( "...." ) );
   }
}
```

And `StatusNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {}`

I registered this converter like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ConverterRegister implements WebMvcConfigurer {

     @Override
    public void addFormatters( FormatterRegistry registry ) {
       registry.addConverter( new ConvertersContainer.StringToStatusConverter() );
       WebMvcConfigurer.super.addFormatters( registry );
    }
}
```

And the controllerAdvice:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class Advice {

   @ExceptionHandler( StatusNotFoundException .class)
   protected String handleStatusNotFoundException(StatusNotFoundException ex) { ...   }
}
```

When I breakpoint the method `Status#findStatus(...)` is well executed but the exception is never catched in `@RestControllerAdvice`. What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try to catch that exception and logging if it is thrown?

Comment: @JonathanJohx yes I can catch it

Comment: Should your handler method be `public`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Spring wrappes all exceptions thrown during the conversion's process and throws a `org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException` instead of user's custom exception.

In my mind this behavior is not normal, if an exception is thrown during the conversion, this exception should take precedence over all framework's exception. So to solve this issue, we have to `extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and override its `protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleTypeMismatch(...)`.

Thanks @Eric (the guy commented the question above).